# How call a method from Class A Static to Class B non-static (form)

Tags: c#, .net, static

How can I call a method from class A (static - file2.css) to class B (nonstatic and contains the form - file1.css)? Same namespace.

Simple code:

file1.css

```
namespace Optimizer
{
    public partial class frm_Main : Form
    {
        
        public void AppendTextConsole(string text)
        {
            txtConsole.Text += text;
            ...
        }
        

        public frm_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
...
```

file2.css

```
namespace Optimizer
{
    public static class Example
    {
        public static void Runaway(string command)
        {
            frm_Main.AppendTextConsole("test"); //< ERR0R
            
            using Process process = new()
            {
...
```

From file2.css, I try to call "AppendTextConsole" method (file1.css, that contains the Main form).

Error: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'(CS0120).

I've been reading on stackoverflow and have tried a lot of code, why is it so difficult?

Comment: You have to instantiate the non-static class

Comment: A non-static method is an instance method on an instance of the object. You can't call `frm_Main.AppendTextConsole` without an object of type `frm_Main` being used. If you don't have that object, where does `txtConsole` come from in the method?

Comment: @NetMage txtConsole is a multiline textbox in the form that receives the response from a command application. I don't want to send the textbox object every time I call the command program.

Comment: `class Example` has no connection or relationship to `frm_Main`. You could have more than one `frm_Main` open at a time - how do you expect method `Runaway` to know which `txtConsole` in which `frm_Main` to use? You must pass it every time, or use some type of single instance pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To call an instance method you need an instance of the class holding it. There are two options - create the instance (i.e. `new frm_Main()`) and I highly doubt that this is what you actually need here, or pass instance as the parameter for static method:

```cs
public static void Runaway(frm_Main form, string command)
{
    form.AppendTextConsole("test");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `new frm_Main()` initiates the instance each time that the code is executed. The application, from the form, sends a command to a static function (class Example) to execute a command application. I want to send the response to the form (textbox txtConsole).
The program will make many calls to that function, so I don't think it is a good idea to always start an instance or send the form handle.
But you have given me an idea: send to the example class the textbox handler when the form is loading and then, from the example class, create a global variable.

Comment: @karmany yes, that is the option too (though I didn't want to mention it because usually it is a poor design to rely on such static variable). Another option is to just make the `Runaway` an instance method on `frm_Main`.